# Sum and product in given range

Tags: algorithm, math

Given four positive integers [image: S_1], [image: S_2], [image: P_1] and [image: P_2], is there a way to quickly find any two integers [image: a] and [image: b] such that:

- [image: S_1 \leq a+b \leq S_2], and
- [image: P_1 \leq ab \leq P_2]?

When [image: S_1 = S_2] and [image: P_1 = P_2], there is a closed-form [image: O(1)] solution to this using quadratic equations. We simply have to find the roots of [image: a^2 - S_1*a + P_1] and it will give us a suitable [image: a].

When [image: S_1 = S_2], I know how to solve it in [image: O(log S_1)] by noticing that the curve [image: f(a) = a(S_1 - a)] is convex and so we can just binary search for a suitable [image: a].

When [image: P_1 = P_2], it can be solved in [image: O(sqrt P_1)] by factoring [image: P_1] and looking for a pair of factors that sum to a value within the range.

When both of them are ranges, however, I can't think of any algorithm that can solve this efficiently. There are some possible heuristics, like fixing one of the two (iterating through the smaller range, etc.), or immediately reporting that no pair exists when the largest possible product that can be made with two integers summing to [image: S_2] is smaller than [image: P_1], etc.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to come up with anything that would work in the general case that is faster than iterating through everything in either [image: O(|S_2-S_1|)] or [image: O(|P_2-P_1|)] (possibly with some extra smaller factors). Is there a nice algorithm, or some fancy mathematics, that gives a faster solution?

Alternatively, is there a way to prove that iterating terminates quickly? (After handling some corner cases, etc.) I'm not interested in the number of valid pairs; finding any pair will do. It seems that iterating over the product and trying to find a corresponding sum tends to quickly find a solution if the range of allowable sums is sufficiently large. Could there be some sort of proof of this?

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Are the ranges of `S1`, `S2`, `P1` and `P2` restricted in any way? For example, if they're all strictly positive, that should be easier to solve than the general case, because, e.g. neither `a` nor `b` can be greater than or equal to `S2` or `P2`. So the search range is limited to `1..min(S2, P2)`.

Comment: Yes, they are guaranteed to be positive; I think even this version is hard enough.

I've updated the question; thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Just an observation, but `max(S1 - b, P1/b) <= a <= min(S2 - b, P2/b)`. Maybe characterizing this inequality can help finding O(1) solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve it in O(sqrt(P2)) time.

1. Find these sums: small_sum = i + ceiling(P1/i) and big_sum = i + floor(P2/i) for i between 1 and sqrt(P2).
2. If small_sum > big_sum or big_sum < s1 or small_sum > s2 then i isn't partn of a solution. Move on.
3. Otherwise, max(small_sum, s1) min(big_sum, s2), and all values between "good sums." For any of these, let j = good_sum - i. Then i + j is a value between s1 and s2, and i * j is between p1 and p2.

We're checking at most sqrt(P2) values of i, and for each of these values we're doing constant work.

Edit -- Ruby implementation

```
def solve(s1, s2, p1, p2)
  max_i = (p2**0.5).floor
  1.upto(max_i) do |i|
    small_sum = i + (p1/i.to_f).ceil
    big_sum = i + (p2/i.to_f).floor
    next if big_sum < s1 || small_sum > s2 || big_sum < small_sum
    good_sum = [small_sum, s1].max
    puts "sum: #{i} + #{good_sum - i} = #{good_sum}, #{s1} <= #{good_sum} <= #{s2}"
    puts "product: #{i} * #{good_sum-i} = #{i*(good_sum-i)}, #{p1} <= #{i*(good_sum-i)} <= #{p2}"
    return
  end
  puts "no solution"
end
```

Comment: I haven't been able to fully understand why (and if) your solution always works, but I don't think the O(log P_2) "binary search" solution is correct; if it was correct, we can find a nontrivial factor of n in O(log n) by setting S1 = 1, S2 = n, P1 = P2 = n and just running your algorithm to find a pair. But integer factorization is a hard problem.

Comment: That said, I just tested it, and this algorithm doesn't seem to be correct. On query S1 = 1, S2 = 99, P1 = 99, P2 = 99 it gives a = 5, b = 20, but 5*20 = 100, not 99. Some correct outputs would have been a = 3, b = 33 or a = 9, b = 11. Maybe it's only a bug, at least I hope so. https://repl.it/JPYG

Comment: You're right. Need to check all i. I'll fix it soon. Sqrt time

Comment: @RobinYu I restored the correct code. Try it now. Sorry about the binary search -- I had an 'insight' right before I left and made a fast change without checking it.

Comment: The new version seems to be correct, and I can kind of grasp how it works now. I've upvoted and accepted—thanks!

Comment: You don't actually need to start with 1; you can start at the ceiling of the min positive solution to (x^2) + (s2 * x) - (p1) (taking advantage of the fact that a is minimal when b-a is maximal). Need to be careful if you're given impossible values of s2.